# Add background color on root node in material tree

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to add a background color to all nodes on hover:

```css
.mat-tree-node {
  :hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 220, 0, 0.1) !important;
  }
}
```

It is working only for leafs, although  the 'fruit' node has the class "mat-tree-node"

[source](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjc6yo-zmeapf?file=app/tree-nested-overview-example.scss)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have typo mistake. add this code to your hover style

```
.mat-tree-node:hover {
      background-color: rgba(255, 220, 0, 0.1) !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The hover style should apply to `.mat-tree-node`, so you have 2 solutions:

```css
.mat-tree-node {
  &:hover {
      background-color: rgba(255, 220, 0, 0.1) !important;
  }
}
```

**OR**

```css
.mat-tree-node:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 220, 0, 0.1) !important;
}
```